# How do I go about this error displayed on my wordpress site after I enabled debugging?

Tags: wordpress

[shows the error message displayed on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQigC.png)
My WordPress site prompted a critical error today and at first, I thought it was a plugin conflict but it wasn't. When I enabled debugging, I saw the log on the picture. How do I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of context in regards to deprecation error for `5.9`:

> WordPress is not fully compatible with PHP 8.0 or 8.1. All remaining known PHP 8.1 issues are deprecation notices.

> Please note, a deprecation notice is not an error, but rather an indicator of where additional work is needed for compatibility before PHP 9 (i.e. when the notices become fatal errors). With a deprecation notice, the PHP code will continue to work and nothing is broken.

- See [WordPress 5.9 and PHP 8.0-8.1](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/01/10/wordpress-5-9-and-php-8-0-8-1/)

If you're not in a development environment you can edit `wp-config.php` line 82, `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` and set the value to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the clearer context you provided, it helped. However, I personally set "WP_DEBUG", to true to get a hint of what was wrong with my site because it was and still displaying, "there's a critical error on this site". Now that I have a hint, my question is how I can get rid of the critical error. Can you help with that?